# Redirecting www.example.com to example.com using github pages?

Tags: git, .htaccess, github, dns, github-pages

If we have `https://example.com` and `https://www.example.com` hosted on Github pages using custom domins and we wish to redirect from `https://www.example.com` to `https://example.com` how can we do that.

IIUC this has to be setup on Github since they are handling the DNS for custom domains and HTTPS certificate generation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [Github] are handling the DNS for custom domains

No, the *DNS* for your domains is handled by you. You can point your `A` and `CNAME` records to Github-managed IP addresses.

To resolve your problem you need to make your `www.example.com` a `CNAME` pointed to `example.com`. Also you need to check that your file `CNAME` in `example.github.io` repository has only `example.com` without `www`.

https://help.github.com/en/articles/setting-up-a-www-subdomain

See this example:

```
$ host cheetahtemplate.org
cheetahtemplate.org has address 185.199.111.153
cheetahtemplate.org has address 185.199.108.153
cheetahtemplate.org has address 185.199.109.153
cheetahtemplate.org has address 185.199.110.153

$ host www.cheetahtemplate.org
www.cheetahtemplate.org is an alias for cheetahtemplate3.github.io.
```

https://github.com/CheetahTemplate3/cheetahtemplate3.github.io/blob/master/CNAME